# Escaping HTML in JSON in rest callout

Tags: apex, json, rest, string

I am sending some html content inside json in the body of a REST callout from Salesforce to Dotdigital per their [specs](https://developer.dotdigital.com/docs/send-transactional-email-using-a-triggered-campaign) which is working well overall.

`string.escapeHTML4` is handling most of the special characters I have tried in testing, but including a single backslash \ returns an error from the endpoint :

> "message":"Could not parse the body of the request based on the content type \"application/json\" ERROR_BODY_DOES_NOT_MATCH_CONTENT_TYPE"

This could be an issue w the endpoint (dotdigital), but wondering if there is something else I should be using to escape the string?

Before I added the escapeHTML4 I was getting errors when the string included double quotes, but that is working fine now.

Note that double backslash (`\\`) does not return an error, just single.

Comment: Hi. WHat about triple ` \\\ `?

Comment: triple backslash -> error;
four backslash -> success;
i see the pattern, but dont know what to make of it.

Comment: if you're sending JSON content it's better to follow javascript/ecma script rules for escaping thus escapeEcmaScript() is a better choice.

Comment: ```escapeEcmaScript()``` is good - its handling all sorts of characters without any issue. however my next operation is no longer working properly. it is replacing carriage returns and line feeds w br html tags using ```replaceAll('\r\n|\r|\n', '<br />');```  i've tried to find the right pattern but failed.  will post that as a separate question unless you have any insight to share on this front. thx

Comment: i cant quite figure out what is going on under the hood, but `replaceAll('\\\\r\\\\n|\\\\r|\\\\n', '<br />')` works w escapeEcmaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from hand rolling to creating the JSON by serializing an apex class using `System.JSON.Serialize` which handles the escaping.

With EscapeECMAScript I ran into issues with / characters like https://google.com coming over as https://google.com which I did not need.